# Excel VBA For Each Loop Copying and Pasting info

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach, excel-2010

I am working on code that is essentially going through each sheet through a Workbook and copies all the content in it to paste in in the final Sheet in the Workbook. I currently just have everything paste into Sheet3 as a test, but the issue is it will only copy the content of whichever Sheet I have open when I run the Macro into Sheet3. It will paste the same content from the single Sheet into Sheet3 as many times as I have Sheets, instead of copying the content of each sheet. My current code is this:

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
'
' Copy_Paste Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
   Dim Current As Worksheet
         ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
         For Each Current In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            Range("A2", Range("k1048576").End(xlUp)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet3").Select
            Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            MsgBox Current.Name
         Next Current
End Sub
```

I tried returning it to Current each time, like having the first line in the loop be Current.Range("A2", Range("k1048576").End(xlUp)).Select or making the first line Sheets(Current).Select but each would only give errors when I tried to run the code.

Comment: `Current.Range("A2", Current.Range("K1048576).End(xlUp))`

Comment: Side note, you should probably skip Sheet3 (lots of answers on this site for how to do that). Also, you could read [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba0).

Comment: Using Current.Range("A2", Current.Range("K1048576).End(xlUp)) gives an "Select method of Range class failed" error

Comment: Yes, because you can't `Select` on a sheet that isn't active, but you shouldn't be selecting anything here anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code could look like whilst avoiding `Select`

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
'
' Copy_Paste Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
    Dim Current As Worksheet, lRow As Long, lRow3 As Long
    lRow3 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("K" & Sheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
    For Each Current In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Current.Name <> "Sheet3" Then
            With Current
                lRow = .Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("A2:K" & lRow).Copy
                Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & lRow3).Paste
                Debug.Print "Current Sheet was: " & .Name
                lRow3 = lRow3 + lRow 'this already offsets by 1 due to starting at A2
            End With
        End If
    Next Current
End Sub
```

Notice I used `With... End With` to avoid having to retype `Current` over and over again (at the places where there's a dot after a space).

Answer (score 0):

### Create a Summary Sheet

```vb
Option Explicit
     
Sub CreateSummarySheet()
'
' Copy_Paste Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'
   
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Create Summary Sheet"
    
    Const SUMMARY_NAME As String = "Summary"
    Const SHOW_MESSAGES As Boolean = True
   
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Delete existing destination (Summary) sheet.
    
    Dim dsh As Object:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if it doesn't exist
        Set dsh = wb.Sheets(SUMMARY_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not dsh Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
            dsh.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    ' Add a new destination worksheet.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet:
    Set dws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)) ' last sheet
    dws.Name = SUMMARY_NAME
    
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Loop and copy.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, AreHeadersCopied As Boolean
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If Not sws Is dws Then ' exclude destination worksheet
            With sws.UsedRange
                If AreHeadersCopied Then ' copy headers?
                    Set srg = sws.Range("A2", .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)) ' no!
                Else
                    Set srg = sws.Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)) ' yes!
                    AreHeadersCopied = True
                End If
            End With
            srg.Copy dcell
            If SHOW_MESSAGES Then
                MsgBox "Copied ""'" & sws.Name & "'!" & srg.Address(0, 0) _
                    & """ to ""'" & dws.Name & "'!" & dcell.Resize( _
                    srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Address(0, 0) & """.", _
                    vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
            End If
            Set dcell = dcell.Offset(srg.Rows.Count)
         End If
    Next sws
                
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data copied to the summary sheet.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
                
End Sub
```